# How to choose files to download in deluge using deluge-console?

Tags: files, bittorrent, console, deluge

I would like to ask if there is any command to choose between files to download in Deluge that can be used in the console (deluge-console).

I'm using it on a Raspberry Pi and as I mostly connect via SSH, web interface or any other GUI is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in deluge-console.

However you can use the Deluge Thinclient setup and connect to your daemon from your pc with the Deluge client installed and setup locally as per the Deluge ThinClient guide:

http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find commands for deluge-console

https://whatbox.ca/wiki/Deluge_Console_Documentation

Comment: There's nothing mentioned about files selections.

Comment: Could you explain more, what are you exactly doing?

Comment: I'm running my Raspberry Pi as a torrent machine. I'm using Deluge as a torrent client. I need to operate Pi via SSH and so the only option how to control Deluge is deluge-console. And what I need is a way to select which files from a torrent I want to download and which I don't.

Comment: So, given that you don't have any kind of GUI to work with, I see your question is that you want to see all the downloadable files and be able to choose the right ones. If this is the case, the thing is, there is no way to use deluge-console that way (at least have never faced). When you have added files, then of course you have many different options to deal with, whether you want to continue downloading them or not. You just need to get the magnet links outside deluge-console first. When in deluge-console, with 'help' command you will see all the possibilities.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to stick to doing the selection using web interface. Shame there is not a command-line variant. Thanks anyway.